# How to display a column from one table which is not in the other table but the field name is same

Tags: sql-server

SQL SERVER:

```
SELECT tblModule.ModuleID tblActivity.ModuleID,
FROM   tblActivity
       LEFT JOIN tblModule
            ON  tblModule.ModuleID LIKE 'Null'
            AND tblModule.ModuleID = tblActivity.ModuleID
ORDER BY
       tblModule.ModuleID
```

Ok so in here I am trying to display the `ModuleID` from `tblModule` which isnt available under `ModuleID` in `tblActivity` this code doesnt work it says :

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

The question itself is -Using an outer join query list any modules which have no activities timetabled for them.(5)

Comment: The syntax error is the comma before `from`. No idea what `like 'Null'`is supposed to be, maybe `is null` but then it can't match the value in the other table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a comma (,) after your list of fields, you also haven't included any comma (,) between your 2 fields.

```
SELECT tblModule.ModuleID, tblActivity.ModuleID 
FROM tblActivity 
LEFT JOIN tblModule ON tblModule.ModuleID LIKE 'Null' 
    AND tblModule.ModuleID = tblActivity.ModuleID 
ORDER BY tblModule.ModuleID
```

Is what you're looking for, although the left join is potentially flawed. You're probably looking for this instead :

```
SELECT tblModule.ModuleID tblActivity.ModuleID 
FROM tblActivity 
LEFT JOIN tblModule ON tblModule.ModuleID = tblActivity.ModuleID 
ORDER BY tblModule.ModuleID
```

Basically, LEFT JOIN tries to fit the requirement and otherwise will join with NULL fields.

Answer (score 0):

First you have extra coma here `tblActivity.ModuleID ,`

The `NULL` comparsion should go in the `where`

```
SELECT tblModule.ModuleID,   tblActivity.ModuleID
FROM tblActivity
LEFT JOIN tblModule
    ON tblModule.ModuleID = tblActivity.ModuleID
WHERE tblModule.ModuleID IS  NULL
Order by tblModule.ModuleID
```